Loop cut and Curve Modifier stop working properly
Outline is not on over the object but at its origin.  (Blender 4.1.1)



Yes, it does not seem to work like before. I don't know if this is done intentionally by the developers, if not I would consider this a bug and therefore offtopic for this site. You should report it as a bug via the menu Help > Report a Bug.

It works in 4.0.2, i'd say too it's a bug.

I can reproduce here in 4.1.1, 4.2b, 4.3a  Linux, so yes it certainly looks like a bug and should be reported (Header > Help) ... (check for previous reports.)  A side-effect is that this post is off-topic on Blender SE, because we're not the people to help you out with a fix.

It is a bug. You can track it using the link:
https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/123138

Thanks GM, you understand, the close is nothing personal... quite the opposite. :)

It would be nice if you could edit that answer to include the link of your bug report in here, so that people who are interested in the topic can follow it up.
